# How to update the ui on drag down the screen(pull to refresh)?

Tags: java, blackberry, pull-to-refresh

I want to send a server request on drag down the screen and update the ui using response from the server.
For this I have tried the following :

```
    new ScrollChangeListener() {
    public void scrollChanged(Manager manager, int hScroll, int vScroll) {
        try {
            if(scrollingFieldManager.getVerticalScroll() < 0 ){
                //send request
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }   
};
```

But this works only when the content needs to scroll.I want to refresh the ui whenever the user drag down the screen.

How to achieve this?

Comment: ScrollChangeListener will works only there are contents to scroll. Like in Android, pull to refresh is not available in Blackberry 5-7. Its available in BB10.

Comment: in touch screen phones, you can do this by gesture movement. but in non touch phones, you cant do this.

Comment: refer this - http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Swipe_gestures_trackpad_1226851_11.jsp

Comment: You mean it is impossible in non touch screens?